# NameError (uninitialized constant OAuth Did you mean? OAuth2)

Tags: oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 on RoR 5.0.7.

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

but I got an error on production environment and I can not start rails apps. My local developing environment is no problem to run it.

The error on production.log is

```
NameError (uninitialized constant OAuth Did you mean?  OAuth2)
```

if I replaced

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

to

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
```

and bundle update then there is no errors and RoR is running.

My production environment is

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Phusion_Passenger/6.0.2
ruby 2.4.6p354
```

Comment: Is your app configured to handle OAuth 1 and 2 style tokens? Could be an issue with existing data.

Comment: I want to replace OAuth1 to OAuth2. and My Developing environment is running without any errors. Do you mean old OAuth1 data exists on production environment? How can I check it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You should be able to check it in the console somehow, but how you do it depends on how you're saving the current tokens

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. I cleared all sessions on DB and The apps is running without errors now.

The command I did is
    RAILS_ENV=production rake db:sessions:clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the session data to remove the existing `OAuth` token data. You can't use both token types simultaneously.

Per your comment (leaving an answer in case someone else has this same problem) you need to run:
`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:sessions:clear`